# QGIS equivalent to "Features to Line" ArcGIS tool

Tags: qgis, features

I have a python script in Arc10 that uses the features to line tool. I however don't have the license to run it. I was wondering if there is a Qgis tool or process that would essentially do the same thing?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the ET GeoWizards add-on toolbar in Arc 10 that provides the same functionality for free with no license requirement. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to access those tools in a Python script. It would be a manual method.

Answer (score 5):

The **geometry tools** menu in Qgis has a number of options for converting features to lines

[image]

There is also the points to path plugin mentioned in this blog post http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/12/30/qgis-plugin-of-the-week-points-to-paths/ athough it doesn't appear to be in the official repositry.

For scripting these menu items are avaliable from the sexante plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Does the "Polyons to Lines" tool in the "Vector" menu in QGIS not do what you want?