# Border from Polygon shapefile

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile polygon that shows the extent of a state. I need to highlight only the *boundary* of the state. Can I do that in QGIS?

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you add a screenshot?

Comment: yes, of course qgis can do that. What have you tried so far? what went wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Visual option:

- right-click the layer, choose `properties`
- choose the tab `symbology`
- set the `fill style` to `none`

Your polygon is now transparent but for the edges.

---

Data-level option

- go to `vector -> geometry tools -> polygons to lines` and run the algorithm on your polygon

Your polygon is now a line-ring.

Comment: I think there is no need to convert the polygon into a polyline, a simple polygon with none fill and some outline style will probably be enough. Of course, it depends on further processing.

Comment: I think so too, but some people like grand solutions to minor issues.

Comment: Hahahah..that is so true!

Answer (score 2):

For display purposes, you can always set the boundary to be a color and the fill style to be none.

If you'd like to change the underlying data from polygon to line, there's a tool to do this. In ArcGIS the tool to complete this is `Feature to Line`. Using that tool name as a search on this site, I found a similar question:  [QGIS equivalent to "Features to Line" ArcGIS tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44358/qgis-equivalent-to-features-to-line-arcgis-tool) which has good screenprints in the answer (use `Vector | Geometry Tools | Polygons to lines` to convert the polygon shapefile to a line).

Comment: Smiller posted like half a minute after I did, and his answer if written more conclusive @Taras.

Comment: The answers were posted simultaneously, and since I'm not a QGIS user I included my sources. Personally I find it helpful to know how an answer was derived.

Comment: No problem! (I mostly haunt the QGIS threads to learn the similarities and differences in the programs for my own use.)