# How do I split polygon into line segments?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-grass-plugin

My question exactly matches with this one : [How do I split polygons into line segments?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32192/how-do-i-split-polygons-into-line-segments)
but the solution is outdated, I am not able to find v.type.bl option under the grass dropdown in QGIS 3.8. Neither I am able to comment on that page. When I am using v.split option(setting maximum number of vertices in a segment=2), splitting happens at multiple points even on the same edge of the polygon.

Comment: Have you tried the QGIS tools `polygon to lines` and `split lines`? If so, how is the result not satisfactory?

Comment: Have you tried the "Polyons to Lines" tool in the "Vector" menu in QGIS? A screenshot can be found on this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44358/qgis-equivalent-to-features-to-line-arcgis-tool

Comment: yes, I applied split lines after polygon to lines conversion! a single edge is splitted into multiple segments by doing so, I have no idea why is this happening